# Understand Nginx error log

Tags: nginx

I had Nginx error log files like:

```
2016/12/16 14:24:45 [error] 2758#0: *506 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 109.61.223.87, server: www.mydomain.fr, request: "GET /download/50/MSMxOz0jM3owLS4rZnJxLAcYExcdCQkdBRMHRQIMGhoCEB4fDQUaEhkKDwkZUwwKr+Xj9+Xa4eL81vrq/uzj/K/3+/x5qulrqiorq+prquWB2bz5A/kbz_ii_v41.exe?sign=global-rus_treid_2?static?cr=60c1ec2384?signtool=osslsigncode-2?rnd=trnt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "dlc.certainlesson.ru"
```

What is the meaning of `host: "dlc.certainlesson.ru"` ?

Or error log like:

```
2016/12/16 15:50:45 [error] 2743#0: *85931 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning: require(/home/ubuntu/myapp/releases/20161216145901/vendor/composer/../guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/Exception/InvalidArgumentException.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ubuntu/myapp/releases/20161216145901/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2850
PHP message: PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/ubuntu/myapp/releases/20161216145901/vendor/composer/../guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/Exception/InvalidArgumentException.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/ubuntu/myapp/releases/20161216145901/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2850" while reading response header from upstream, client: 163.172.129.17, server: www.myapp.fr, request: "GET /download/ad/zNzM2NjE1pndwsPIg5WUz97Yz6eoramnvavpvaejv6mpqaqkoKe6saG6rvarr/S4vKq+v4aHl7uVh5WJhJnUioSCioPMwMXFx8PHzMrLzQdmkBM/all-in-one_checker_crack_v3_8.exe?sign=global-rus_treid_2?static?cr=4af9a4e12c?signtool=osslsigncode-2?rnd= HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "dlc.magic-terrify.ru", referrer: "https://dlc.magic-terrify.ru/download/ad/zNzM2NjE1pndwsPIg5WUz97Yz6eoramnvavpvaejv6mpqaqkoKe6saG6rvarr/S4vKq+v4aHl7uVh5WJhJnUioSCioPMwMXFx8PHzMrLzQdmkBM/all-in-one_checker_crack_v3_8.exe?sign=global-rus_treid_2?static?cr=4af9a4e12c?signtool=osslsigncode-2?rnd="
```

Has anyone been able to run code on my server without my knowledge?

Thank you in advance for explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The `HTTP GET` is a request of data from a specified resource, in your case this resource is `dlc.certainlesson.ru`.

On the 15:50:45 log is looks like that the file **all-in-one_checker_crack_v3_8.exe** getting requested with `HTTP GET` using

> https://dlc.magic-terrify.ru/download/ad/zNzM2NjE1pndwsPIg5WUz97Yz6eoramnvavpvaejv6mpqaqkoKe6saG6rvarr/S4vKq+v4aHl7uVh5WJhJnUioSCioPMwMXFx8PHzMrLzQdmkBM/all-in-one_checker_crack_v3_8.exe

return **No such file or directory**

Hope this will help.